# How to install SVN plugin with Jetbrains PHPstorm (on Linux MINT)?

Tags: svn, phpstorm, linux-mint

Previously it worked in the IDE. SVN works, but is not included into PhpStorm.

Comment: There is nothing to install -- it's already bundled by default. Maybe you have disabled it? If so -- just -re-enable it again in `Settings | Plugins`

Comment: Thank you very much.It helped me. SVN -integration plugin was not available, but after installing SVNToolBox, was installed automatically.